# Url rewrite Camel Case to hyphen in IIS 7

Tags: .net, xml, url-rewriting, iis-7

I am trying to create a rule as xml that will take any part of the url in camel case and separate the words with a hyphen

e.g. ThisUrl to this-url

I have the following xml but I'm stuck on what to write as a replacement.

```
    <rule name="Camel Case Rule">
      <match url="[A-Z]([A-Z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*" ignoreCase="false"  />
      <action type="Redirect" url="" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.